# Selenium Webdriver: How to fire an event on the page that would driver.quit()

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was wondering if I could create an event on the HTML page I am testing that would fire `driver.quit()` function "on the server side".

Also, I am wondering whether if I close the window with `window.close()` or even manualy will it be closed properly? Do I have to run `driver.quit()` anyway? What if I don't run `driver.quit()` and close the window, will there be a hidden running process on my PC?

Comment: `window.close()` will close the current window that driver has focus on. `driver.quit()` is to close all the browser instance. `Do I have to run driver.quit() anyway?` - depends on the use case, `will there be a hidden running process on my PC?` - NO

Comment: What kind of event you are looking for, we can fire up JS code through Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

1. AFAIK there is no way to create an event on the web page that will cause normal closing the driver as with `driver.quit()`.
   Web driver is managed from the side where Selenium code is launched (your PC / server machine etc), not from the page it runs on side.
2. In case single web driver browser tab (window) only is opened closing the driver with `driver.close()` will close it properly as with `driver.quit()` method. However if you only closing the web driver browser manually this will not close `webdriver` process on you machine.

Comment: Still, you can run a JS code through Selenium, right? and that JS code could create an event

Comment: Sure, but as I see he is asking about some kind of event created by/on the web page that will close the driver.

Comment: Just like we use `ExecuteScript("window.open()");` we should be able to close it too. However I am not really sure what's the ask here.

Comment: We can do it with JS from inside the driver, but not from the web page itself to close the driver browser. At least I'm not familiar with such option.

Comment: yeah, I was just thinking if we can embed `window.quit()` or `window.close()` in the HTML, Just like we change the attribute value or we add an attribute to the tag. I also have never done it before with selenium, but this sounds interesting.

Comment: But changing web element attribute etc. on the client side is done from driver side while here he is asking the vise versa, to fire event on a web page to close the driver.